# Testing Apollo Client subscriptions

Tags: unit-testing, graphql, subscription, apollo, apollo-client

I recently added support for subscriptions via WebSockets to my React+Redux+ApolloGraphQL application. Since doing that I cannot run my unit tests anymore.

The problem I come up with is:

```
Unable to find native implementation, or alternative implementation for WebSocket!
```

It seems there is not an available implementation for WebSockets on the node environment where I run my tests.

There are a couple of proposed solutions in [this bug report](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/issues/87) that involve using the 'ws' library for node but I cannot make them work. Either I cannot load the library properly, or I can but then the application doesn't work.

I was thinking of a way to load the library depending on the environment I'm on but:

1. I don't know how to do that
2. I don't know if it's the right approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share a reproduction?

Comment: A reproduction of what? I haven't been able to run my normal tests since I added subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

How are you running your tests? In my case, I'm using Jest, so I've put inside `setupTests` file (which is executed before running all of your tests) this code:

```js
import WebSocket from 'ws';
Object.assign(global, {
  WebSocket,
});
```

This is necessary because for tests which aren't running in browser, there's no native Web Socket implementation.